# Why the multiplicative group $G_m$ is called a 1 dimensional torus?

Tags: topological-groups

I am reading a definition saying that an algebraic group over a field $K$ is called a torus if it is isomorphic to product of copies of the multiplicative group $G_m = K^*$. I don't understand why this definition, because $K^*$ is the affine line removing the origin, and it does not look like a circle. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The complex points are homotopic to a circle. Anyway, the group is abelian and resembles a torus from the theory of Lie groups.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_torus